# mkvirtualenv gives permission denied error

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

When running: 
    mkvirtualenv test

I get following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2378, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 830, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 999, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1198, in install_python
    mkdir(lib_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 451, in mkdir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test'
```

Why is the 'test' virtual environment not created? I did try to chmode -R 777 the virtualenv folder, but that did not solve it. I  do have python 2.7 and 3.4 installed on Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely getting the error because you cannot create the virtualenv folder in the current working directory.

If you do an `ls -ld .` you'll see the output of the current directory you're running the command from, e.g.:

```
➜  ~  ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x+ 114 tfisher  staff  3876 Jun 26 08:46 .
```

and if you do a `whoami`, you'll get the name of your current user.

The interesting bit in the output is typically the first portion of that `ls -d .` command: `drwxr-xr-x+`.  This means "this is a directory, with Read, Write, eXecution for the user, then Read eXecute for the group, and finally Read and eXecute for everyone else."

If you do not have `w`rite permission, you will not be able to create the files and folders that virtualenv needs.

If the current directory is one that you feel that you should personally own, e.g. `/home/musicformellons`, and you have sudo permission, you can rectify this by running:

```
sudo chown `whoami` .
```

The reason why this didn't just simply work is likely because you followed a guide that had you install a "virtualenvwrapper" using sudo permissions.

Comment: Thanks, however after a small detour I am back at the same problem. I editted the error-message slightly as now it also seems to mix python2 and python3. However I checked and do have rights on current directory... so that is not the problem...

Comment: After changing the right on the (nondefault) systemfolder in which virtualenvs are made and also changing some bashlines it is working as it should. So far the python2/3 does not seem to hurt. I will mark your answer as correct as it was indeed permission related. However permission on the virtualenv folder and not on current folder.

Answer (score 1):

i have did the same the issue i found is :

> `echo $WORKON_HOME`

you will find : ***/home/user/.virtualenvs/extra_path***

just yoy need to remove this extra_path added after ***.virtualenvs*** path
from your ***.bashrc*** and then *source* it again try again creating *mkvirtualenv*

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can't create a test virtualenv.